# squid Transparent proxy

Tags: proxy, squid

I have two proxies for squid

```
A:cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 8111 6000  no-query

B:cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 8112 6000  no-query
```

A for http traffic and B for https traffic

how to write a acl rule for users when he visit http go to A,When https go to B?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use following URL:

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/MultipleWebservers

Or this should work according to me.

```
acl secure port 443
acl simple port 80
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 8111 6000 no-query name=phttp
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 8112 6000 no-query name=phttps
cache_peer_access phttp allow simple
cache_peer_access phttps allow secure
```